# Is there preferred hardware on which to run simplewallet to ensure random wallet generation?

Tags: monero-wallet-cli, randomness

Would a Monero wallet generated with simplewallet on a Raspberry Pi be as secure as one generated on an Intel-based Mac or PC? How can one determine whether one's random number generator is good enough?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Trezor](https://forum.getmonero.org/4/academic-and-technical/2495/experimental-trezor-firmware-testing) built on a 32-bit ARM Cortex has a true Random Number Generator [(RNG)](http://www.st.com/content/st_com/en/products/microcontrollers/stm32-32-bit-arm-cortex-mcus/stm32f2-series/stm32f2x5/stm32f205re.html).

Having analog-to-digital (A/D) converter making very small voltage measurements can assure randomness.  Most electrical engineers are very familiar with the "thermal noise floor" that in a statistical sense is governed by **K*T*B*NF** physics equation. K = Boltzman's Constant, T = Temperature in Kelvin, B = Bandwidth in Hertz, NF = Noise Figure of amplifier feeding the A/D converter(s).